# Reloading Clojure nrepl automatically

Tags: clojure, nrepl

The way that I'm reloading the nrepl in Clojure seems too bulky.

When I load a Clojure project and nrepl, I:

- Create a keyboard macro to input and return something like `(use 'my-namespace.core :reload)`.
- Next I bind the keyboard macro to something else, usually `C-tab`.
- Finally, every time I switch into the nrepl, I execute `C-tab`, and the repl reloads.

This seems like a lot of unnecessary work. I've looked around at getting the namespace programmatically, or with `C-c C-e`, but nothing seems to fit quite right.

Isn't there an easier way?

Thanks.

Comment: If you press `,` and then `clear` doesn't it do what you want? Alternatively, maybe `,` and then `ns`?

Comment: Those are nice, thanks, but they don't reload the repl, by which I mean load the saved s-expressions into the repl. So that if one newly wrote `(def life-means? 42)` in their file they would be able to save that file, write `life-means?` in the repl, and get back `42`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way is to just load your current file:

```cl
(define-key clojure-mode-map
    (kbd "C-c C-l") 'cider-load-file)
```

It's also possible to keep `(use 'my-namespace.core :reload)` in your file, navigate there with `isearch` and <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>.

Personally, I almost never use a REPL and evaluate either the whole buffer with <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> or single expressions with <kbd>e</kbd> (via [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy)).